# How do you group an Excel PivotChart by a column not selected in category?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, powerpivot

Does anyone know if its possible to select one column in an Excel PivotChart (i.e. Name in my example) but sum the values by ID without displaying the ID column in the chart?

In the example below, we have two Johns. I want to view both of them in the chart like in chart two, but I don't want to display their ID fields in the chart.

[image: Excel grouping issue]

[EDIT]

Real case scenario is that I need to filter on top 10 file views by file name. And if we have a bunch of files named image1.jpg (because people don't properly name their files), we end up bucketing them all together and it looks like image1.jpg has way more views than it actually has; causing the chart to be skewed. I know it might be confusing to have two same data labels, but oh well. :) The user will just have to drill into one to see other details.

I did find a clean way of doing this using hierarchies in PowerPivot, but with a large dataset the performance is horrible.

[image: PowerPivot Hierarchy]

Create a hierarchy in powerpivot with ID and Name. Use the hierarchy in the PivotChart category. Only ID field shows up initially. Expand entire field and the names show up. Hide level ID, and voila. You get all Names without ID column, but only to be used on smaller datasets.

[image: Hide hierarchy level]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**datamodel**,

easiest way to do this is created a **calculated column** in PowerPivot window where you will combine *filename* AND *file id*.

[image]

With that, it's very easy and still should be quite good from performance perspective. Better yet if you could prepare this column in your import file / on your server.

Result could then look like this:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing :) Except I used squared brackets for the ID ;)

Comment: Awesome, I love how PowerPivot is easy-to-learn and makes our work a waaaay more interesting :) Also, could you please accept the answer then?

Comment: Yeah, loving PowerPivot... still more room for improvement, but it's a great tool!

Answer (score 1):

From a data visualisation point of view it will be most confusing to have two data points with the same label and no means of differentiating them. So, having the ID in the X axis is actually helping the reader to make sense of the information.

From a technical point of view, you can create a chart that is based on the pivot table, but is not a pivot chart. Use the pivot table as the source for a regular chart and select only the Name as the X axis label.

If the pivot table dimensions may change when it is refreshed, you can use dynamic range names  to ringfence the ranges required for the chart.

In the screenshot below, the label range chtLabels uses the formula

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$F$38,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$F:$F)-1,1)
```

The range chtValues uses

```
=OFFSET(chtLabels,0,1)
```

When adding the range names to the chart source dialogues, they must be preceded with the sheet name or the file name.

[image]

Comment: Although this is very helpful, it still doesn't give me what I need. I have many pivot charts with PowerPivot as the datasource and was hoping there was a nice and clean way to achieve what I need without 'hiding' pivottables. I made an edit in the orig post with real case scenario.